# how can i using multiton in DB?

Tags: java

Database (table of characters) can be accessed only through a class implementing the interface type IConnection. 
The Database should be the Singleton but only a concrete connection should use it (not the main function).
 The connections should be Multitons: there exists only three of them returned by the getInstance method in the round-robin fasion (1 2 3 1 2 3 ...). 
The client (main function) gets the connection object and using them it accesses the database. 
Complete the following code. In the main function: get 4 connections and prove that they all use the same database.
 Then prove also that in fact (inspite of 4 initialized references) there exists only 3 connection objects.

I couldn't provide continuance...example code below...

```
interface IConnection {
    char get(int index);
    void set(int index, char c);
    int length();
}

class Database {

    private char[] tab = new char[100]; /* ... */

    public static IConnection getConnection() {
        return Connection.getInstance();
    }

    private static class Connection implements IConnection {

        private Database db;
        private static IConnection instance = getConnection();

        public static IConnection getInstance() {

        public char get(int index) {
            return db.tab[index];
        }

        public void set(int index, char c) {
            db.tab[index] = c;
        }

        public int length() {
            return db.tab.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your interface. I cannot read this. I do note that you aren't passing a key to `getInstance()` (Multiton is a Singleton where `getInstance()` takes a key).

Comment: I edit the code...actually.It's my first class with singleton and multiton....I couldn't do it :S

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you are asking here? Are you asking how you should implement getInstance?

Comment: In fact I want make tasks as written.If I solve this tasks I will learn about something  multiton and singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible answer

```
public static interface IConnection {
    char get(int index);

    void set(int index, char c);

    int length();
}

public static class Database {
    private char[] tab = new char[100];

    public static IConnection getConnection() {
        return Connection.getInstance();
    }

    private static final class Connection implements IConnection {
        private Database db;
        private Connection() {
            super();
        }
        private static IConnection[] instance = new IConnection[3];
        static {
            for (int i = 0; i < instance.length; i++) {
                instance[i] = new Connection();
            }
        }
        private static int i = 0;
        public static IConnection getInstance() {
            return instance[(i++)%instance.length];
        }

        public char get(int index) {
            return db.tab[index];
        }

        public void set(int index, char c) {
            db.tab[index] = c;
        }

        public int length() {
            return db.tab.length;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IConnection conn1 = Database.getConnection();
    IConnection conn2 = Database.getConnection();
    IConnection conn3 = Database.getConnection();
    IConnection conn4 = Database.getConnection();
    if (conn1 == conn4) {
        System.out.println("conn1 has the same reference as conn4");
        if (conn1 != conn2 && conn1 != conn3 && conn2 != conn3) {
            System.out.println("conn1 != conn2 AND conn1 != conn3 AND conn2 != conn3");
            System.out.println("Quod erat demonstrandum");
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
conn1 has the same reference as conn4
conn1 != conn2 AND conn1 != conn3 AND conn2 != conn3
Quod erat demonstrandum
```